# ASP.NET Identity Framework UserSecret no UserId Column

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I'm developing a multitenant application on Mvc 5 and the new Asp.net Identity.  The challenge is that two users can have the same username, just not on the same tenant.  I have this figured out for the most part, but for some reason all of the tables generated by the Identity framework have a UserId column, except the UserSecret entity's table.  Is there a reason for this?  I want to make sure I'm not missing something before I replace it with an implementation that has a UserId column.

Comment: Hi orourkedd, I'm trying to implement a multi-tenant solution using ASP.NET Identity I'd appreciate your input on my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20037145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default implementation was designed for single tenant apps, it left multitenant app support to be done via the extensibility (plug in your own stores, etc)  For RTM, there also is no longer a separate UserSecret store, as that has been rolled into the User itself (PasswordHash).