# ASP.NET Identity, multiple users with the same username, but belonging to different companies. Override FindAsync?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity, usermanager

I'm new with MVC and EF, and I'm working on a project where I use Identity for user and role management. In the predefined login function from Visual Studio there's a function named FindAsync, used to get the user by username and password. In my case there can be more than one user with the same username and password, but they will belong to different companies. I would like to know the best approach; should I override the FindAsync function (and other functions if necessary) and add another parameter, or should I implement user and role management myself, without Identity? Or is there another, even better solution?

If the best solution is to override the function, then I'm a bit unsure of how I should do it, since the source code for UserManager is not yet open.

Below you can find the login function and takeouts from my models:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(Login model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Any help is more than welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I think I would create my own implementation of `UserManager` and create a method like `FindByCompanyAsync(string userName, string password, string companyName)`

In this method you could search the user by getting all users of the UserManager and use a LINQ expression to filter it on username and company name.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this thread, which addresses the same problem as mine:
[How to implement Multi-tenant User Login using ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037145/how-to-implement-multi-tenant-user-login-using-asp-net-identity)

It seesms like a good approach, and I will try to make my own implementation of UserStore just like he did.

Answer (score 0):

I sent in the companyId to the UserStore and overrode the FindByNameAsync function to filter on both userName and companyId. What I don't like is that I coulden't use the GetUserAggregateAsync function since it's private. Is there any other disadvantages with my solution?

```
public class UserStore : UserStore<User>
{
    public int companyId = -1;

    public UserStore(DbContext context, int companyId)
        : base(context)
    {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    public override Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        if (companyId < 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("There is no companyId associated with the UserStore.");
        }
        return QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync<User>(QueryableExtensions.Include<User, ICollection<IdentityUserLogin>>(QueryableExtensions.Include<User, ICollection<IdentityUserClaim>>(QueryableExtensions.Include<User, ICollection<IdentityUserRole>>(this.Users, (User u) => u.Roles), (User u) => u.Claims), (User u) => u.Logins), (User u) => u.UserName.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper() && u.CustomerId == this.companyId);
    }
}
```