# Multiple UserManagers

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to have two different **UserManagers**.

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

app.CreatePerOwinContext<CustomUserManager>(CustomUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<CustomRoleManager>(CustomRoleManager.Create);
```

Both **ApplicationUser** and **CustomUser** inherit **IdentityUser**.

How do I configure **OnModelCreating** to support the *Roles/Claims/Logins* correctly?

Am I doing something that would be considered bad practice? I just want to completely separate these two types of users. I don't want TPH since I need different required properties.

**UPDATE**

To further explain why I *think* I need this, is because I would like to have different **roles** and **properties** for these two types of users. If they share the same table, I would need a optional one-to-one relation to add properties, allow same UserNames, and who knows what else.

Comment: Can you please be more specific why do you need multiple UserManagers?

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Maybe [this solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628850/microsoft-asp-net-identity-multiple-users-with-the-same-name)

Comment: Have you ever been [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c)? Maybe you can ask others to help you with this.

Comment: I've already seen the solution you suggested, it won't help for different roles and properties. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I'm also curious to see the right solution for your question.

Comment: I already have two UserManagers working (logins, etc), I'm just trying to figure out how to map roles correctly, and also if this is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made two custom **UserManager**s (e.g., `CustomUserManager : UserManager<CustomUser>`) where **CustomUser** inherits from **IdentityUser** and is specified as *Table per Type* with `[Table("CustomUser")]` on the class.

The context needs to be **IdentityDbContext**, or **DbContext** with the same **DbModelBuilder** settings.

Same thing goes for the roles if needed (e.g., `CustomRoleManager : RoleManager<CustomRole>`), they will be *Table per Hierarchy*. Though there isn't much use to this unless you modify the **Authorize** attribute and add the **Claim** to match the **Discriminator** and the role's **Name**.