# Don't make username unique asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-identity

I want to implement custom logic for username validation. Created function `ValidateEntity` for username custom validation but if I provide unique username while creating user then `ValidateEntity` function is hit and If I provide duplicate username then this function is not hit.

**IdentityModel.cs**

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {
            public int AppId { get; set; }
            //other attributes
            public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
            {
                var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                return userIdentity;
            }
        }
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public ApplicationDbContext()
                : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
            {
            }

            public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
            {
                return new ApplicationDbContext();
            }

            protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
            {
                if ((entityEntry != null) && (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added))
                {
                    var user = entityEntry.Entity as ApplicationUser;
                    //custom logic for username validation
                }
                return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
            }
        }
```

In **AccountController.cs**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); //shouldn't it always goto ValidateEntity function?
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

**Update:**
I added `public new string UserName { get; set; }` and now I get error `Name cannot be null or empty` here is the screen shot of data.

[image]

Comment: If you haven't already, it would be worth checking out the answers to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628850/microsoft-asp-net-identity-multiple-users-with-the-same-name)

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this solution, unfortunately it didn't worked.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice for the username field not to be unique, unless you plan to cover that in your custom validator. However you should be able to override the username field in the ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int AppId { get; set; }

    // Override username field
    public new string UserName { get; set; }

    //other attributes
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Additionally, if your database already exists, you must also then remember to remove the unique index UserNameIndex for everything to work.

Comment: I get error: `Name cannot be null or empty` Please see updated question