# Multi-tenant using Aspnet Identity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, multi-tenant

I am trying to create a MVC5 multi-tenant application using Aspnet Identity.  I have done some research and found other answers, [How to implement Multi-tenant User Login using ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037145/how-to-implement-multi-tenant-user-login-using-asp-net-identity), that provides a nuget package for implementation.  Than problem that I have is that the tenant is specified in the constructor of the ApplicationUserStore.

I need to have users go to a login screen from which they choose from a list of available tenant options and then authenticate the user against the chosen tenant.

Does anyone know how to modify the above solution to meet my needs or have another option?

Comment: Any user should login using their primary tenant and then switch to the other tenant from thrre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com supports multi-tenancy using Identity Framework. Also, there is a commerical startup template based on this framework which is multi-tenant. See http://www.aspnetzero.com